# Rails: choose between different root_to routes based on domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

My idea is that if you go to www.my-website.com I want display a "choose country" landing page with links to each of my country based websites like www.my-website.dk, www.my-website.de etc. etc.

I made a routes.rb like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints subdomain: /\Awww\b/ do
    apipie # For API documentation, see initializers/apipie.rb
    draw :api_v1_v2_v3
    draw :api

    constraints ->(request) {request.host =~ /my-website\.com/ } do
      root to: 'my_website_dot_com#landing_page' # anyone going to http://www.my-website.com/ will get this action
    end

    root to: 'my_website#front_page'

    get 'sitemap', to: 'my_websiteouncle#sitemap' # anyone going to http://www.my-website.de/ or http://www.my-website.dk/ etc. will get this action
  end
end
```

Problem is, I cannot have multiple `root_to` with rails 4.2 so how can I change the routes.rb to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Why not add a method in application controller that tests the request.url for your sub-domain and redirects accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
constraints ->(request) { request.host =~ /my-website\.com$/ } do
  get '/' => 'my_website_dot_com#landing_page', locale: :en
end

constraints ->(request) { !(request.host =~ /my-website\.com$/) } do
  root to: 'my_website#front_page'
end
```